# VS runs old version of Silverlight application instead of new one

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I've got a problem with Silverlight, or maybe more with VS2010 Ultimate. I was fooling around playing with it, when in one moment a fix that I wrote didn't fix anything. Investigating why I found out that VS is not running the new version which it just compiled, but rather an old version of application - that's why my changes don't affect it. How to fix it, and what can be the source of the problem? Maybe project configuration file got corrupted or there's something wrong with ASP.NET dev server?

Comment: It's not just happening in VS2010. I ran into it once in a while in VS 2008. If you remove the XAP file in the web project, the new version will be copied from the SL project. Not a real solution but a quick work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem which I had. The thing I did is just painfully simple - I cleared browser's cache :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at the output window?  Sometimes it gives errors that aren't listed in the Error List.

Side note: I didn't see you mentioning extra libraries, but I've had this happen when a change I was making in a library wasn't reflected in another Silverlight application.  For whatever reason, when I was adding a reference to the library it was copying it to the debug directory of my project and only using that version (Specific Version was off).  if you're using custom libraries, you can try deleting the references and re-adding them (this works, a more permanent solution is to add the library to the solution and add it as a project reference).

Comment: Yep, I've looked at the Output - it say that there everything is ok, test page was created etc. I did not extend the architecture of the solution, it's plain Silverlight Bussiness Application template, so there are only two projects in it - the Silverlight part and the Web part.

The problem I've described happened to me for the second time a few minutes ago - I created a new solution, started working on it and it just stopped responding to changes. I've deleted all my code, compiled an functionally empty solution and in my browser there's everything that has been written.